# a="python". I want output: p-y-t-h-o-n. Any loop possible for this

Tags: python-3.x

a="python"
I want output with the help of loop as: p-y-t-h-o-n
I want this code to be dynamic by using input() so that every input entered can be seperated by (-).

Comment: Why do you require a loop per se?

Answer (score 3):

```
a = "python"
b = '-'.join(a)
print(b)
```

unless you really need a loop

Comment: You do not need `list` here. Just `b = '-'.join(a)`

Answer (score 2):

```
a = "python"
print('-'.join(a))
```

Untested, also without a loop

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a loop:

```
s = input('Enter a String ')
res=''
for i in range(0, len(s)):
    res+=s[i]+'-'
res=res[:-1]
print (res)
```

Comment: Enter a String python jupyter spyder anaconda                                                                                                  
p-y-t-h-o-n- -j-u-p-y-t-e-r- -s-p-y-d-e-r- -a-n-a-c-o-n-d-a
Its working....Thanks
Is there any way n- -j, r- -s, r- -a to avoid - before and after space.

Comment: Yes. Just replace `print(res)` with `print(res.replace("- -", " "))`

Answer (score 1):

If you actually need a for loop.

```
a = 'python'

s = ''
#Iterate through each character and make a new string after appending -
for i in a:
    s+=i+'-'
#Remove the last -
s = s[:-1]
print(s)
#p-y-t-h-o-n
```